# Correlation of prime density in sets of the form $\{x^2 + n\mid x\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This question is inspired by [this reddit post to /r/DataIsBeautiful](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/kmthuf/oc_number_of_primes_in_x2_n_for_2x1000000_and/).

In that post a graph is produced of $n$ plotted against the number of primes in the set $\{x^2 + n\mid x\in\mathbb{N} \wedge x < 1000000\}$. Since these are primes generated by a quadratic, these are certain diagonals of the [Ulam Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral). It is well-known that some diagonals of the Ulam spiral have more primes than others - so we would expect that there would be some variation in the graph of this density. But what I found surprising, and what the original poster says inspired them to make the post, is that there are very obvious regions of higher density *in the graph of density* - in other words there is a correlation in the density of primes $D(n)$ in $\{x^2 + n\mid x\in\mathbb{N}\}$<sup>1</sup> and $D(m)$ in $\{x^2 + m\mid x\in\mathbb{N}\}$ depending on $n$ and $m$.

Clearly the correlation is not simple, because there are many arcing regions of higher density-density that are stacked one on top of the other in the graph: in other words it is not simply the case that $D(n+1)$ is likely to be close to $D(n)$; $D(n+1)$ is most likely in *another* high density-density region, but some later small offset $e$ will result in $D(n+e)$ being close to $D(n)$.

What is known about this correlation? Is there a succinct explanation - or failing that, is there a succinct explanation under the assumption of some open question like Hardy-Littlewood's Conjecture F?

1 $$D(n) = \lim_{X\to\infty}\frac{|\{x^2 + n\mid x\in\mathbb{N}, x<X, x^2+n\text{ is prime}\}|}{X}$$

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're asking, at least to me. Can you be more precise about the statistical correlation you mean, and maybe clarify what your notation means?

Comment: I have added the precise definition of D which I thought was too ugly and obvious to include before. Everything else should be standard.
In terms of correlation I mean it very weakly: the values are far from random. A good explanation would explain why we see arcs, not just why they aren't random.

Comment: So, D(n) and D(m) for two values n and m are just two different probabilities, and there's not a sense in which two probabilities (which are just single numbers) can be "correlated." If what you mean is just some functional dependence of D(n) on n, you might want to rephrase the question.

Comment: Have you gone to the reddit post and had a look at the graph posted? That might help. I don't mean to treat $D(n)$ and $D(m)$ as numbers; I mean to treat $n$ as an unknown, then you gain some information about the likely value of $D(n)$ if you know nearby values of $D$.